# Convert date time to string and back to date time

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having a troubles with converting strings to DateTime. Here is what I have. First I convert current date to string (this will be folder name).

```
string dateString = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}", DateTime.Now);
```

Output like this

> 2013-05-16_09-32-47

Then I create a folder. During program execution I get this folder and I need to convert it's name back to DateTime. Try to make it like this

```
DateTime directoreDate = DateTime.ParseExact(directory.Name, "0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it throws FormatException. Can anybody tell me why this happening.

Comment: In debug I see correct directory name.

Comment: If you remove the "0:" from the `ParseExact` string, does it work then?

Comment: Try this string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Use System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\oldfolder", @"C:\newfolder"); to change the name of your Directory

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Answer (score 6):

You are using the same composite format string that you used to format the original `DateTime`. This is not needed for `ParseExact` - drop the `0:` from it:

```
DateTime directoreDate = DateTime.ParseExact(directory.Name, 
                                             "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
DateTime directoreDate = DateTime.ParseExact(directory.Name, "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `0:` from `DateTime.ParseExact`, It was used as a place holder in `string.Format()`.
Use as :

```
DateTime directoreDate = DateTime.ParseExact(directory.Name,
                                          "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```